# How to save a file that data as it can be deleted, edited in future?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iPhone development. I have a question would like to ask. which is the best way to save data into a file? That later, I could get the data from it, and edit it, add new one and delete easily.

*Such as*: I have a *library system* which store information about books. A book will have:

> name, publisher, date published, author, price...

I thought of file ***plist***. But I think file plist is ***readonly***. I can't edit anything in there right? Please help me out. I am so thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plist, you would have to read the entire contents into memory and then re-write it at the end of processing. However, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) is exactly what you want for this.